# How to git commit with persistent exit 0 status?

Tags: git, travis-ci

In Travis-ci I'm using this command.

`git push origin HEAD:${TRAVIS_PULL_REQUEST_BRANCH:-$TRAVIS_BRANCH}`

This all works perfectly fine *unless* there is nothing to commit (response: `Everything up-to-date`).

This is a perfectly fine response in my case, but it results in: `exited with 1.` This is something I would like to avoid. Regardless if it actually is able to commit *or* if all is up to date I would like the response to be `exit 0`.

How can I do this?

**UPDATE:**
As mentioned by @Mort in the comments, `|| true` works, but now I *always* have a positive exit status. I would like to *only* change the Git exit code for `Everything up-to-date`.

Comment: `git push origin HEAD:${TRAVIS_PULL_REQUEST_BRANCH:-$TRAVIS_BRANCH} || true` ?

Comment: See e.g. https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/118217/chmod-silent-mode-how-force-exit-code-0-in-spite-of-error, this is by no means specific to Travis or Git.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to return exit code 0 from a failed command](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36130299/how-to-return-exit-code-0-from-a-failed-command)

Comment: @Mort yes, that works, I did update the question though :-)

Comment: `git push` *should* exit 0 on successful push, *including* "Everything up-to-date". What version of Git are you using?

Comment: Hi @torek, not sure. It is in Travis-ci: https://travis-ci.org/weaviate/weaviate/jobs/295304839

Comment: Opening `Build system information` shows `git version 2.14.1`, which is plenty modern and should not have that kind of bug. But I see on line 982: `The command "git commit -m " updated nightly builds with travis"" exited with 1.` It's not the push that's failing, it's the commit that's failing.

Comment: Ooooo, of course, thanks! Would adding `—force` be the right way to go in this siuation?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Your question isn't unique to Travis, and with that in mind, this has already been answered [on this page](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8123674/how-to-git-commit-nothing-without-an-error). But I will re-post my own version of the most popular (and best) answer there, here, as I don't have enough reputation to mark this as a duplicate.

So, you're having the classic `exited with a 1` problem because you tried to commit when there was nothing to commit. But you still want it to `exited with a 1` if there is an actual problem. Just do this: don't run the commit command at all if you find that there is nothing to commit. You will check beforehand if there are any commits to be had, like so:

```
git diff-index --quiet HEAD || git commit -am 'Jolly ol commit message'
```

It's pretty slick.

Comment: Helped me build this useful alias `git fire` : `git config --global alias.fire '!set -x; git add -A && (git diff-index --quiet HEAD || git commit -m "${*:-WIP}") && git push'`