# Container STATE is Error when the Test Result has Failure

Tags: selenium-webdriver, kubernetes, testng, containers, minikube

I have set up Kubernetes environment locally using minikube. I create a Job which has 3 containers.

- Hub
- Chrome
- App ( Selenium-TestNG)

When I apply/create job, which will set up Hub/Chrome/App. Execute selenium tests.

If all the tests are completed successfully, you will see the status of Container like below

[image: Container List after completion]

The result from webAutomation1 app
[image: log]

The above things are as expected. Looks good in terms of container listing

Now, if we have completed the app(Execution of tests) with some failures like below

[image: fail log]

Then, my container listing will show it as error
[image: error container]

I use ITestListenr to write logs to console as of now. What is that making container STATE to turn Error.? Is there anything I don't see in terms of integration between container and app?

It would be greatly appreciated if someone helps me with this.

Comment: I suppose the return code is not 0 when there is a failed test thus resulting in a exit code in error in the pod?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As per [TestNG exit codes](https://testng.org/doc/documentation-main.html#testng-exit-codes):

> When TestNG completes execution, it exits with a return code. This
>   return code can be inspected to get an idea on the nature of failures
>   (if there were any). The following table summarises the different exit
>   codes that TestNG currently uses.
>
> ```
> /**
>  * |---------------------|---------|--------|-------------|------------------------------------------|
>  * | FailedWithinSuccess | Skipped | Failed | Status Code | Remarks                                  |
>  * |---------------------|---------|--------|-------------|------------------------------------------|
>  * | 0                   | 0       | 0      | 0           | Passed tests                             |
>  * | 0                   | 0       | 1      | 1           | Failed tests                             |
>  * | 0                   | 1       | 0      | 2           | Skipped tests                            |
>  * | 0                   | 1       | 1      | 3           | Skipped/Failed tests                     |
>  * | 1                   | 0       | 0      | 4           | FailedWithinSuccess tests                |
>  * | 1                   | 0       | 1      | 5           | FailedWithinSuccess/Failed tests         |
>  * | 1                   | 1       | 0      | 6           | FailedWithinSuccess/Skipped tests        |
>  * | 1                   | 1       | 1      | 7           | FailedWithinSuccess/Skipped/Failed tests |
>  * |---------------------|---------|--------|-------------|------------------------------------------|
>  */
> ```

Your container is probably using the TestNG as the main process, and any test that is not considered `Passed tests` (i.e., exit code different than 0) will result in a pod with the terminated/error state.

You can confirm this by [Determining the Reason for Pod Failure](https://kubernetes.io/docs/tasks/debug-application-cluster/determine-reason-pod-failure/).

e.g: You can check your pod state; the output will be something like this:

```
$ kubectl get my-pod-name -o=json | jq .status.containerStatuses[].state
{
  "terminated": {
    "containerID": "docker://9bc2497ec0d2bc3b1b62483c217aaaaa1027102a5f7ff1688f47b94254",
    "exitCode": 1,
    "finishedAt": "2019-10-28T02:00:10Z",
    "reason": "Error",
    "startedAt": "2019-10-28T02:00:05Z"
  }
}
```

and check if the exit code matches your TestNG status code.

Comment: @Edurado, perfect! I did check that. Thank you for your answer. It did tell me where is the problem.

Comment: Is there a way we always send status code 0 to the container? So that it ends up with the completed status ?

Comment: You may append [`|| true`](https://stackoverflow.com/a/36131305/7641078) to your job command...