# Peoplesoft : Unix command returning error code 1 from EXEC() but working from putty

Tags: shell, unix, peoplesoft, peoplecode

I am trying to run below command from EXEC() peoplecode but getting return code 1.

```
&cmd = tail -n +2 /dirname/filename.csv | split -d --lines 20 - --filter='bash -c "{ head -n1 /dirname/filename.csv; cat; } > $FILE"' --additional-suffix=.txt /dirname/filename.csv_;

CommitWork();

&returncode= Exec(&cmd, %Exec_Synchronous + %FilePath_Absolute);
```

The command is working as expected from command line. Any help will be appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

I'm assuming the &cmd is quoted properly and just a formatting issue here in SO.

On the command line, after you test the cmd, do `echo $?`to show the return code on the last command. If it does show 1, but is 'correct', you take a look at:

[How to return exit code 0 from a failed command](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36130299/how-to-return-exit-code-0-from-a-failed-command)